# microservices - Best Practice for dealing with ghost records in transactionless systems

Tags: database, microservices, nosql

I am developing a system based on NoSQL and microservices architecture.

I have a general architectural question -

Le'ts say I have three types of documents - Countries, Cities and Streets.
Where Street holds a CityId and City holds a CountyId.

At the country service I need to develop a **deleteCountry()** methods that:

1. Deletes the country.
2. Requests the city service to delete all the cities by countryID.
3. The city service in its turn then requests all the streets service to delete all of the streets by cityIds.

**Problem:** if this process fails after the country deletion, in a transaction-less world, I am left with a few 'ghost' documents.

- I can manage the failure in my orchestration so that it will clean
  after it, but this is not scalable (code-wise) solution.
- I can work with a choreography pattern but it doesn't really solve it.
- I can run a periodical sweeping process that will clean documents but it will
  be hard to manage and will leave time holes where the problem will still exist.

What is the best practice to remove ghost records from a NoSQL db.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a service whose job it is to scan for and eliminate ghosts.

Answer (score 2):

In the scenrio you described, one solution can be to have a statefull orchestration component that can deal with the process's integrety, something like a [Saga in NServiceBus](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/message-correlation).

You start the process by processing the `DeleteCountry` command that sends 2 messages, one to the country component and the other to the cities component.

Both components will reply to the 'saga' and the saga will handle the completion or failure of the operation based on the state/results from the components doing the work.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In this example an aggreggate is separated over several microservices. Cascading updates and deletes indicate that `Countries`, `Cities` and `Streets` all belong to the same concept.

In a microservice architecture I should be allowed to shutdown the `CitiesService` and it will have no business impact. In a well designed microservice architecture, this situation should either never happen or it should not cause any problems. If you run into a situation similar to your example, then you're doing microservices wrong.